# What are some sites with good free video tutorials on ASP.NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, video

Besides [www.asp.net/learn/](http://www.asp.net/learn/), what other sites have good free video tutorials for ASP.net(c#) and everything related to asp.net and the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: I think he wants something in addition to asp.net/learn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [Official site](http://www.asp.net/LEARN/). It has loads of video tutorials.

A quick google shows up the [BestTechVideos](http://www.bestechvideos.com/category/development/aspnet) site which aggregates tech videos.

Comment: Any thing other than this site means http://www.asp.net/LEARN/

this is a common site tat every one using

Answer (score 2):

[LearnVisualStudio.Net](http://www.learnvisualstudio.net/) ?

You mentioned nothing about the the videos being free.

Answer (score 2):

[Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/) has some great asp.net screencasts.  I was also able to somewhat filter the screencasts by using [this search](http://channel9.msdn.com/Search/Default.aspx?Term=screencast%20asp.net).

Answer (score 0):

[monzoor the Trainer](http://www.manzoorthetrainer.com/) also contain great bit of videos regarding ASP.Net using C#.